# How to open iOS app from browser?

Tags: ios, http, url, url-scheme

I have to open my iOS app whenever user open a link of my app in browser. I have already used a like `myApp://`  but i want to open my app even when user open an http link a from browser. Just like pinterest. Pinterest opens app even if i open a regular http link like this `http://www.pinterest.com/pseudoamber/` and using URL scheme as well like this  `pinterest://www.pinterest.com/pseudoamber/`. My app is opening on `myApp://www.myapp.com` now i want to open my app when user open an http link like this `http://www.myapp.com`

Anybody please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var user_agent_header = navigator.userAgent;

        if(user_agent_header.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1 || user_agent_header.indexOf('iPod')!=-1 || user_agent_header.indexOf('iPad')!=-1){
            setTimeout(function() { window.location="myApp://www.myapp.com";}, 25);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but the thing is that i have to open my app even if user write www.myapp.com in browser. for this purpose i'll have to add "http" URL scheme and a host name but i don't know how to do this

Comment: You simply put the above javascript at the website @ www.myapp.com

Comment: it will redirect to mypp:// but if user do not have app in his iPhone then it will generate an error i think. Then what we should do

Comment: what is "myApp://www.myapp.com" ? What should I give for my app ? 
What will happen if my app is not installed in the phone and still the user tries to call for my app ?