# How to edit the Xcode Project for Meteor iOS integration?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I want to create an app icon, splash screen, edit the app name, and set some cordova / app settings.

`meteor run ios` opens up the simulator but doesn't open or the project. Where is that project and does this Xcode project ever get overwritten? I don't want to lose any settings I make.

For example I want to set the [app url scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) so I can implement a [redirect to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077411/how-to-open-ios-app-from-browser). I also want to set cordova preferences to [disallow over scroll](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html). Typically I would do these things from within the .xcodeproj but where is it and when does it get overwritten / reset?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what i have seen from the docs and my experience so far

- `meteor run ios` only **runs the iOS emulator with your code** in it. The code related to this build is in .meteor/local/cordova-build but is temporary and will get overwritten all the time
- `meteor run ios-device -p yourlocalip:yourlocalport` **will launch XCode with the cordova-built .xcodeproject, and a local server on your computer**. It is intended to make you able to run and debug your code from an actual iPhone device, with the changes you make on your computer to the code repercuted instantly on the iPhone screen. You need your computer and your phone to be on the same Wifi to enable this feature. The code related to this build is in .meteor/local/cordova-build but is temporary and will get overwritten all the time
- `meteor build /Path/To/Builds/Directory/NewBuild -p yourserverhost:yourserverip` **will actually create the cordova-built .xcodeproject pointing to your real server** at the path you specified. From this project you can customize as much as you want **BUT** you will indeed loose these settings with a new build...

Except if you use the **yourproject/cordova-build-override/** folder !

As described [in the offical cordova meteor docs](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) under "Advanced build configuration" everything you put in this folder will overwrite the files created by meteor during its build. So you can configure everything in the Cordova/Phonegap way there. If you were able to configure your features through Cordova usually, you will be able to do it there.

*Bonus that I have learned the hard way :*

**Always destroy the .meteor/local folder before building one of those three things**, i got stuck in a state where XCode remembered some of my changes to the .xcodeproject and everything was messed up. After destroying this folder, everything went back to normal :)

hope i helped

Mickael

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the path to the Xcode project in your filesystem, it is located at:

```
/path/to/project/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/<project>.xcodeproj
```

You'll have to navigate to your project directory and open `.meteor` because it is a hidden file.

Note: If you want to be able to see hidden files in finder **on a mac**, then type into your terminal `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`, and then restart finder. Change `TRUE` to `FALSE` to only see visible files.

Comment: ...but, future readers: like mcoenca already explained in the accepted answer: changes will be overwritten in the next build.